# move column names to first row in pandas frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I forgot how to move the all the columns in dataframe to first of dataframe in A PANDAS WAY.
-> I wish to add another function where it could also calculate how many columns there are and then assign the name for the new column names.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                  'b': [2,3,4,5,6,7],
                  'c': [2,3,4,5,6,7],
                  'd': [2,3,4,5,6,7],
                  'e': [2,3,4,5,6,7]})
```

Current output:

```
    a   b   c   d   e
0   1   2   2   2   2
1   2   3   3   3   3
2   3   4   4   4   4
3   4   5   5   5   5
4   5   6   6   6   6
5   6   7   7   7   7
```

Expected output:

```
    Q1.1    Q1.2    Q1.3    Q1.4    Q1.5
0   a   b   c   d   e
1   1   2   2   2   2
2   2   3   3   3   3
3   3   4   4   4   4
4   4   5   5   5   5
5   5   6   6   6   6
6   6   7   7   7   7
```

Please if possible, I wish to learn more pandas ways of processing frame so please use as much pandas ways as possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One line [`DataFrame.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) + [`DataFrame.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html). You can set the names of columns with [`DataFrame.set_axis()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html)

```
new_df = (df.T.reset_index().T.reset_index(drop=True)
            .set_axis([f'Q1.{i+1}' for i in range(df.shape[1])], axis=1))
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
  Q1.1 Q1.2 Q1.3 Q1.4 Q1.5
0    a    b    c    d    e
1    1    2    2    2    2
2    2    3    3    3    3
3    3    4    4    4    4
4    4    5    5    5    5
5    5    6    6    6    6
6    6    7    7    7    7
```

Comment: This is spectacular! Thank you!

Comment: What does ```DataFrame.T``` do though? The webpage referenced only says it is a property function.

Comment: @Archeologist it transponse Rows and Columns, the idea is that we can use reset_index to transform an index to a column values, so first we use .T to transform columns in index, after that we use reset_index so columns came now like a column values, finally, we use T to transform our column in a row

Answer (score 3):

this is a version:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'b': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   'c': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   'd': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   'e': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})

df.loc[-1] = df.columns.values
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

df.rename(columns=
    {"a": "Q1.1", "b": "Q1.2", "c": "Q1.3", "d": "Q1.4", "e": "Q1.5"}, 
    inplace=True)
```

where i first add a new (last) row `df.loc[-1]` then sort the index (`df = df.sort_index()`) to make it the row (which now has index `-1`), then i reset the index `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` in order to make it start from `0` again.

it outputs:

```
  Q1.1 Q1.2 Q1.3 Q1.4 Q1.5
0    a    b    c    d    e
1    1    2    2    2    2
2    2    3    3    3    3
3    3    4    4    4    4
4    4    5    5    5    5
5    5    6    6    6    6
6    6    7    7    7    7
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vsplit.html#numpy.vsplit)

```
# Use `df.to_numpy() instead of `df.values` mentioned in the docs.
new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df.columns, df.to_numpy()]),
                      columns = [f'Q1.{i+1}' for i in range(df.shape[1])])

  Q1.1 Q1.2 Q1.3 Q1.4 Q1.5
0    a    b    c    d    e
1    1    2    2    2    2
2    2    3    3    3    3
3    3    4    4    4    4
4    4    5    5    5    5
5    5    6    6    6    6
6    6    7    7    7    7
```

Or

You can [`np.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) here

```
             # np.r_[[df.columns], df.to_numpy()]
pd.DataFrame(np.r_['0,2', df.columns, df.to_numpy()], 
             columns = [f'Q1.{i+1}' for i in range(df.shape[1])])

  Q1.1 Q1.2 Q1.3 Q1.4 Q1.5
0    a    b    c    d    e
1    1    2    2    2    2
2    2    3    3    3    3
3    3    4    4    4    4
4    4    5    5    5    5
5    5    6    6    6    6
6    6    7    7    7    7
```

Or

Using [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate)

```
np.concatenate([[df.columns], df.values],axis=0)
```

You can use this if column names can start with `Q1.0` and so on.

```
pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df.columns, df.to_numpy()])).add_prefix('Q1.')

  Q1.0 Q1.1 Q1.2 Q1.3 Q1.4
0    a    b    c    d    e
1    1    2    2    2    2
2    2    3    3    3    3
3    3    4    4    4    4
4    4    5    5    5    5
5    5    6    6    6    6
6    6    7    7    7    7
```

Timeit results:
The df given the question is used for benchmarking

```
# Ansev's answer
In [98]: %%timeit
    ...: (df.T.reset_index().T.reset_index(drop=True)
    ...:             .set_axis([f'Q1.{i+1}' for i in range(df.shape[1])], axis=1))
    ...:
1.93 ms ± 157 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# My answer
In [99]: %%timeit
    ...: pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df.columns, df.to_numpy()]),
    ...:                       columns = [f'Q1.{i+1}' for i in range(df.shape[1])])
    ...:
590 µs ± 43.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Benchmarking with large dataframe of shape `(1,000,000, 5)`

```
large_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,(1_000_000,5)),
                        columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
        a  b  c  d  e
0       3  8  0  8  5
1       7  4  0  0  7
2       5  1  2  6  1
3       8  0  5  5  6
4       0  2  3  1  8
...    .. .. .. .. ..
999995  1  7  3  8  7
999996  5  2  5  1  6
999997  7  4  4  3  5
999998  3  5  2  2  7
999999  6  7  0  8  0

[1000000 rows x 5 columns]
```

---

```
# My answer
In [105]: %%timeit
     ...: pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([large_df.columns, large_df.to_numpy()]),columns = [f'Q1.{i+1}' for i in range(large_d
     ...: f.shape[1])])
     ...:
     ...:
147 ms ± 16.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# Ansev's answer

In [107]: %%timeit
     ...: (large_df.T.reset_index().T.reset_index(drop=True)
     ...:             .set_axis([f'Q1.{i+1}' for i in range(large_df.shape[1])], axis=1))
     ...:
469 ms ± 3.52 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer..nicely done with all 3 np methods, i guess i would go for `vstack`

Comment: @anky Thank you...Yes, I would go with `vstack` too it's more readable IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You can do by:

```
data={"A":[4,3,4],"B":[5,2,7],"C":[3,5,9],"D":[6,3,0]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

df.loc[-1]=df.columns
df.index = df.index + 1  # shifting index
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df.columns=["Q1.1","Q1.2","Q1.3","Q1.4"]
```

Result:

```
  Q1.1 Q1.2 Q1.3 Q1.4
0    A    B    C    D
1    4    5    3    6
2    3    2    5    3
3    4    7    9    0
```

Comment: Method very similar to my answer but result set has too few records: 4 instead of 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                  'b': [2,3,4,5,6,7],
                  'c': [2,3,4,5,6,7],
                  'd': [2,3,4,5,6,7],
                  'e': [2,3,4,5,6,7]})
df.loc[-1,:] = df.columns
df.index += 1
df.sort_index(inplace = True)
df.columns=['Q1.1','Q1.2','Q1.3','Q1.4','Q1.5']
```

result:

```
  Q1.1 Q1.2 Q1.3 Q1.4 Q1.5
0    a    b    c    d    e
1    1    2    2    2    2
2    2    3    3    3    3
3    3    4    4    4    4
4    4    5    5    5    5
5    5    6    6    6    6
6    6    7    7    7    7
```